# How to search for huge list of search-terms from a corpus using custom function in tm package

Tags: r, match, text-mining, tm, corpus

I want to select and retain the gene names from a corpus of multiple text documents using the tm package. I have used a custom function to keep only the genes defined in "pattern" and remove everything else. Here are my codes

```
    docs <- Corpus(DirSource("path of the directory containing text documents"))
    f <- content_transformer(function(x, pattern)regmatches(x, gregexpr(pattern, x, ignore.case=TRUE)))
    genes = "IL1|IL2|IL3|IL4|IL5|IL6|IL7|IL8|IL9|IL10|TNF|TGF|AP2|OLR1|OLR2"
    docs <- tm_map(docs, f, genes)
```

The codes are working perfectly fine. However, If I need to match a larger number of genes (say > 5000 genes), what is the best way to approach it ? I don't want to put the genes in an array and loop the tm_map function, to avoid huge run time and memory constraints.

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want the fastest vectorized fixed-string regex, use `stringi` package, not `tm`. Specifically, look at `stri_match*` functions (or you might find `stringr` even faster if you're only handling ASCII - look for Hadley's latest versions and comments).

But if the regex of gene names is fixed and known upfront, and you're going to be doing a *lot* of retrieval on those few strings, then you could tag each document for faster retrieval.

(You haven't fully told us your use-case. What % of your runtime is this retrieval task? 0.1%? 99%? Are you storing your genes as text strings? Why not tokenize them and convert once to factors at input-time?)

Either way, tm is not a very scaleable performant package, so look at other approaches.